# Rails 5.1 (postgresql): efficient DB query to select parent records and filtered children records

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a task-management system where a `project` has many `tasks` and a `task` can be assigned to `users`.

I want to add a "My Tasks" page that shows all the projects with the current user's tasks beneath.

Like this, where each task is assigned to the `current_user`.

```
Project #1
- task 1
- task 2
Project #2
- task 1
- task 2
Project #3
- task 1
- task 2
- task 3
```

What I'm trying to achieve with pseudo-ActiveRecord code:

```
@projects_with_tasks = current_user.projects.includes(:tasks).where(tasks: { user_id: current_user.id })
```

And then I would like to iterate over each project, listing the tasks assigned to the current_user:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= project.title %>
  <ul>
    <% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
      <li><%= task.title %> - <%= task.due_date %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

It seems simple enough, but when I call `project.tasks` it goes back and loads ALL the tasks for the project, not just the ones for the current_user.

Is there a way to efficiently get the project and filtered list of tasks?

The best solution I have at the moment is grabbing all the projects first and then iterating over them and making a separate DB query to retrieve all the filtered tasks.  However, if someone has 20+ projects they are involved in (likely in my use case), then that's 21+ queries (1 for all projects and then 1 for tasks).  Never mind the case where some users will have 50 projects...

I prefer to keep everything in ActiveRecord, but I also know this may be a case to create a query object that with some SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your models are defined like this:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

You can query projects with filtered tasks with this query:

```
@projects = Project.includes(:tasks).joins(:tasks).where(Task.table_name => { user_id: current_user.id })
```

`.includes(:tasks)` - to eagerly load tasks

`.joins(:tasks)` - to perform INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN

`.where(Task.table_name => { user_id: current_user.id })` - to filter tasks by user

You can also add scope to your `Task` model:

```
scope :for_user, ->(user) { where(user: user) }
```

After that, the query can be written like this:

```
@projects = Project.includes(:tasks).joins(:tasks).merge(Task.for_user(current_user))
```

The output will be the same.

**NOTE:**

I guess you won't do it, but still it's worth mentioning that you should avoid calling `project.tasks.reload` while iterating over projects loaded with any of the above queries. It will force reloading `tasks` association without filtering by user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something like `has_many :tasks` in your `User.rb` file and a `belongs_to :project` in your `Task.rb`

Then you can simply fetch `current_user.tasks.includes(:project)` and then get unique list of Projects from there.